# Need help conceptualizing blockchain for supply chain scenario

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

Consider the following participants in a blockchain:

1. Supplier
2. Manufacturer
3. Distributor
4. Retailer

The Supplier ships 1000 lbs of raw material, as a single unit or batch, to the Manufacturer. The information about this shipment is stored in the Blockchain. Then, the Manufacturer produces a different product based on the same raw material from the Supplier. At this point, the Manufacturer has their own product, units, batch, and so forth. For example, from that 1000 lbs shipment, the Manufacturer may produce 5 different products in different sized batches with different units. Then, the Manufacturer ships 2 of those products to two different Distributors, who then can take that and further break it down into different batches and units, which they then ship to their Retailers. Basically, the process is the same through out the entire supply chain, where the previous party provides something that gets broken down and transformed by the recieving participant.

To me, it seems like there will need to be many blocks that all "relate" to each other, based on some parent/child relationship or dependency. For example, the supplier would be the first block/parent. Then the manufacturer can have X number of blocks/children that are dependent on that block, and so forth.

Am I seeing or conceptualizing this wrong? Is there a better way? Any idea how this could be implemented in Sawtooth, from a high level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a step back and rethink your business problem using blockchain abstractions.

A useful starting point for you could be to model the participants, assets and transactions in your model using the Hyperledger Composer tool which is designed for modelling business relationships on the blockchain. Check it out here;

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/

Comment: The business scenario is simple tracibility. Thanks for the suggestion of using Composer but it currently doesn't support Sawtooth (yet). How would handle the Assets as they transform from 1:N (one to many) in the blockchain. When you start with raw material, it is "transformed" through out the supply chain, starting off as a single unit then being "transformed" into different products and units. Sounds to me that I need to create new assets for every "new product", even if it originated from the same raw material. Perhaps I need to just add a reference to the original raw material?

Answer (score 0):

The [Sawtooth Supply Chain](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain) project is available, which implements something very similar using Hyperledger Sawtooth.

> This is a distributed application to help you trace the provenance and other contextual information of any asset. It can be used as-is or customized for different use cases. This distributed application runs on top of Hyperledger Sawtooth, an enterprise blockchain.